# Are there rules governing pre- and/or post-modification of noun groups by participial adjectives?

Tags: grammar

Which of the expressions "supplies needed" and "needed supplies" is / are correct?

> 1. Have we now received all the needed supplies?
> 2. Have we now received all the supplies needed?

Is there a pattern one can use to predict whether a participial adjective is used prenominally, postnominally, or both? And if both, may there be differences in meaning?

Comment: I'm sure this has been addressed before. // Here is the food that the troops need. // Here is the food needed by the troops. // Here is the food needed. -- Here is the needed food. Sometimes, the shortest versions, with the bare participial adjective, sound better with premodification or postmodification. 'The provided food' doesn't sound as natural as 'the food provided'. 'All the remaining food' and 'all the food remaining' both work well.

Comment: The answer might depend on the specific head noun and the specific past-participle shaped word that are involved: in your case, "supplies" and "needed". (It is doubtful that the easily available grammar sources out there will have a decent answer for you.) Actually, your question (which asks about a pattern) probably won't be that simple to answer.

Comment: Sometimes, for some pairs, the meanings can be (slightly) different depending on whether the adjective occurs attributively or postpositively. (*CGEL* page 445-6, [12].)

Comment: There is some difference in these constructions. "I want to see the mail delivered" can mean "I want to see the delivery of the mail" _or_ "I want to see the already delivered mail" but "I want to see the delivered mail" can only mean the second option. And if you want to restrict it to this morning's mail, you can only say "I want to see the mail delivered this morning" (now triply ambiguous!) but not "I want to see the delivered this morning mail" (bad grammar) or "I want to see the delivered mail this morning" (makes the 'seeing' this morning, not the delivery).

Comment: In [this thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95916/order-of-participial-adjective), @John Lawler says that it's neither simple nor convenient to have to trace the history of deletions to passive constructions resulting in the 'needed supplies' / 'supplies needed' type of strings. If I'm reading him correctly.

Comment: I've provided a thorough reply to a related question at http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26774/3796.  My answer probably contain information of interest to this question (especially in the second half of the answer).

Answer (score -1):

Difference: Provide (present tense) **must** be preceded by a noun while provided (past tense) denotes a context where the event is over (may or may not be followed by a noun because **the meaning will not change either way**)

In order to know when to use "provide stuff" or "stuff provided", you must first identify the subject(s) of your point. For "provide stuff" the noun precedes the phrase while "stuff provided" precedes the noun.

> **They** provide stuff for the army to use. (known contributor, same event and meaning)

VS

> There is stuff provided for the army to use. (anonymous contributor, same event and meaning)

As long as the meaning does not chan, it would be correct to use either forms.

I hope this clarifies your doubt!