# Sentence construction, adjective position

Tags: syntactic-analysis, construction

I need to phrase a title, and I am not sure what the best option is:
*Detect visited page without analyzing its features* or  *Detect page visited without analyzing its features*

Comment: Niether is particularly clear out of context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of participial adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95916/order-of-participial-adjective). @FumbleFingers has: < I can't really see how "The police released details of the jewellery stolen" is any different to "...jewellery taken". But in that case the more natural sequence is "...stolen jewellery", whereas "...taken jewellery" sounds totally weird. Is there some specific difference between stolen/taken as used in such a context, or is it just "one of those things"? > Here, '[the] visited page' and '[the] page [that has been] visited' are both OK.

Comment: Both examples have the same interpretation. "Visited" is a verb in both.

Answer (score 0):

They have two different meanings.
Detect visited page without analyzing its features, means that the detection is done without analyzing its features. On the other hand  ``Detect page visited without analyzing its features'' means detect a page which was visited by someone who didnt analyze its features.

Comment: There's certainly an ambiguity, but I wouldn't say the different meaning you suggest was the default one. / Clipped style, as used here, tends to add scope for loss of clarity. One can't assume that the lack of a comma isn't merely down to headlinese conventions.